# Change certain video source on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'am wondering how I could go about changing only one of the following two sources to webm and the other to .mp4 in my video tag:

HTML:

```
    <video controls="controls" preload="auto" id="video" onclick="this.play();">
        <source src="fragmenten/real_schade.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </source>
        <source src="fragmenten/real_schade.webm" type="video/webm"> </source>
            Your browser doesn't support the video element.

    </video>
```

JQuery:

```
var bvideo = document.getElementById('background');

$("#car").on('click', function(){
    bvideo.pause();
    showPlaceHolder();
    showVID();
    $("#video").attr("src","fragmenten/real_schade2.mp4");
    $('#video').attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
});
```

This only inserts a source into the  tag directly, how can I change the two sources I've given with the video tag to change to .mp4 and .webm and not change both sources to one source / insert a video src into the  tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace all sources dynamicall without changing the file extension you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    changeVideoTo("fragmenten/real_schade2");
});

function changeVideoTo(name) {
    $("#video source").each(function () {
        var oldSource = $(this).attr("src");
        var fileExtension = oldSource.split(".")[1]
        $(this).attr("src", name + "." + fileExtension);
    });
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/beznbxqc/2/

Comment: Actually, it only works to a certain extend.. it replaces the sources within my <video> tag but still plays the old video, do you have any idea as to how I should fix this?

Comment: you will have to call `.load()` on the video element at the end. I do not have example videos to show this to you though...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703519/dynamically-load-and-play-html5-video

Comment: Thank you sir, for all your effort, the issue has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#video source:nth-of-type(1)").attr('src', videoFile);
$("#video video")[0].load()
```

Try this:

Comment: You should add an explanation to this answer. As it is, it appears in the "Low Quality Posts Queue" And is likely to be deleted.

Comment: @v.k. Sir, do you know why a video, after replacing the source(s) of said video still plays the old video?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code to change the first source:

```
$("#video source:first-of-type").attr("src","first/source.mp4");
```

and this to change the second source:

```
$("#video source:last-of-type").attr("src","first/source.webm");
```

I hope it works :D