# Bootstrap video tabs, load videos only when click tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I have a section on my website using `nav-tabs` from bootstrap, the problem is that this tabs contain videos. And I have a total of 14 video tabs. Everything is working, the problem I'm dealing with is the slow loading of the website, and I think this might be caused by loading all the videos (even the videos in the hidden tab).

How could I possibly tell the browser to load the video only when the tab is `.active`?

My HTML (I display three tabs here, but there are a total of 14):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="videos">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#one">1 &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green;"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#two">2 &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green;"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#three">3 &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green;"></span></a>
        </li>
</ul>




 <div class="tab-content">

                <div id="one" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 video-nr">
                        <h3>Video 1</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-xm-12">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video">
                            <video controls>
                                <source src="video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                <source src="video-1.webm" type="video/webm">
                                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="two" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 video-nr">
                        <h3>Video 2 </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-xm-12">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video">

                            <video controls>
                                <source src="video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                <source src="video-2.webm" type="video/webm">
                                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="three" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 video-nr">
                        <h3>Video 3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-xm-12">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video">                  
                            <video controls>
                                <source src="video-3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                <source src="video-3.webm" type="video/webm">
                                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a video player like http://www.jwplayer.com/ or https://flowplayer.org/ which offer playlists instead of using multiple tabs? Otherwise you will probably find yourself building one. Loading is one issue, handling start and stop to avoid multiple videos playing will be the next.

Comment: If you need to do it like this, you have to add click listeners to your tab controls and load the videos dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703519/dynamically-load-and-play-html5-video

Comment: I'm not interested in a video player. By default HTML5 Videos don't auto play. So that is not a problem. The only problem is I don't want them to load.

Comment: You should use ajax to load the videos from the server when a tab is clicked